# Is it possible to use both fabric and turbo in a react native library

Tags: react-native, react-native-turbomodule, react-native-fabric

I'm new to React Native Architecture and I was trying to make a library using the community tool: `npx create-react-native-library@latest my-awsome-library`, but I get faced with the choice of selecting either Fabric or Turbo. I tried to merge them both but I get compilation errors like:

```bash
[CXX1429] error when building with cmake using /Users/MyUser/Sources/my-awsome-library/example/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/default-app-setup/CMakeLists.txt
```

So I'm wondering if it's even possible to use both on the same library, because I have a usecase where I need to setup some config and keys on each platform before I can use fabric to use the views.